# Dropping iOS 4 support

Tags: ios, version, itunes

I have an app that currently works well on iOS4-6. However, I would like to make use of newer libraries that only support 5 and above. What are the ramifications of dropping an OS version? How do the people on iOS4 backup their apps? Should I tell them to backup up the IPA file from iTunes? I know I have been in a few situations when I needed a file for an older iOS version and couldn't get the file back.

If you had to drop an iOS version, what would you do?

Comment: You can just use weak-linking instead.

Comment: FYI - I am currently running an iPhone 3G which does not support iOS 5.  Many of the apps on my 'phone have updates in the App Store that require iOS 5.  iTunes downloads these Apps but will not install them to my iPhone so my iOS 4 apps (and data) are never overwritten.  In fact, when I sync with iTunes, I get a consolidated warning that lists the apps that were not installed to my iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to drop support for iOS 4, ramifications can be multiple and surely some user will be caught in what you described as "needing a file that you could not get back".

In any case, I think that telling your users to backup the app data and the IPA file is a good strategy (you might devise another one, like the one suggested by @benzado, but the one you are proposing will work for sure, even in the case that the user decides to update the app through iTunes) to reduce the risk.

The only thing that I do not know is how you are going to tell them to do so. Maybe through an intermediate release saying: this is the last one for iOS4? Not sure.

On the other hand, I am not sure you really need to drop support for iOS4.

Have a look at [this post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html) for a general approach.

If you are just thinking of adding a new frameworks (existing for iOS5/6 and not for iOS4) it is just a matter of weak-linking those frameworks and then conditionally including the headers for those frameworks.

Say that you want to support Twitter; then you conditionally include the headers:

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_5_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_5_0
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#endif
```

and also conditionally guard the use of Twitter methods:

```
Class tweeterClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");
if (tweeterClass != nil && [tweeterClass respondsToSelector:@selector(canSendTweet)]) {
   ...
}
```

(this code will only be executed on iOS5/6).

As to weak-linking, go to your target options, display the build phases and there you can add the new frameworks under "link with frameworks"; only ensure that you select the option "optional" on the right side (see picture).

[image]

Comment: Maybe he wants to use `[NSManagedObjectContext performBlock:]` (iOS 5) to simplify some Core Data code. Weak linking is not a panacea.

Comment: @benzado `- [NSObject respondsToSelector:]` is.

Comment: @benzado: he wrote "make use of newer libraries"... so, my answer... in any case, let the OP clarify what he is trying to achieve...

Comment: @H2CO3 There is no point to using `performBlock:` if you have to wrap each use with a conditional and also handle the case without it. Let's not have a debate here, I'm just saying weak-linking won't help if you can't isolate the "new stuff" in a clean way.

Comment: @sergio The OP wants to know about the ramifications for dropping iOS 4, your answer is simply one strategy to avoid doing so.

Comment: @benzado: you are right. I added my thoughts about the ramifications.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that, with the ridiculously high update rates and high percentage of users on 5.0+, 4.x support should start being phased out. It's a lot of extra work for the developers to try and keep three major SDK versions straight and making sure each and every new and/or modified feature is written (potentially) three different ways or with safeguards to strip features from older version adds additional unneeded complexity. It is my subjective opinion that it's time to abandon 4.x development support.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Sorry I didn't make it clear. The libraries I am thinking of using are paid 3rd party libraries which apparently require minimum iOS 5. That was the reason for the question. I really appreciate all of the answers!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you drop support for iOS 4, tell existing users:

1. Sync with iTunes on a computer to make a backup of their apps and data. (They should do this anyway.)
2. Only download app updates on the device and do NOT download app updates in iTunes on a computer. The device will never download an update it cannot run, but iTunes may overwrite your backup copy with a newer one that won't run on your device.

The fact is, most people who are still using an older iOS device don't regularly sync it with iTunes, and so they won't lose the app unless they delete it individually or wipe the whole device.